# Convert a TFDS dataset to tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, mnist

Previously I got an error on

`from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data` because its no longer part of tensorflow 2.0

I was suggested in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32790) post to replace it with

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
input_data = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
```

But now Im getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GAN.py", line 79, in <module>
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('../../MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
AttributeError: '_OptionsDataset' object has no attribute 'read_data_sets'
```

How can I convert `input_data` to the right format to be able to use `read_data_sets` from it?

Answer (score 0):

As the library has changed for TF2.0 so are its functions. So, `read_data_sets` is not required and functioning.`input_data` is already your dataset consisting dictionaries of `image` and `label`. Which you can access like

```
image, label = input_data["image"], input_data["label"]
```

Read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview#tfdsload_a_dataset_in_one_line) for more.